# Slow refresh of canvas in android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am doing an app wich paints a rectangles over preview camera in Android. But problem is that appears previous rectangles, so I think that Canvas's refresh is too slow compared with preview Camera.

This is my code:

In my activity class:

```
if (face.orientation != TYPE_FACE_ON_TRACK.face_notDetected) {
                        drawView.setPaint(true);
                        drawView.setSize(mat.size());
                        drawView.invalidate();
                        drawView.paintRect(face.rect);

                    }
```

And this my onDraw and my paintRect funcions:

```
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        mCanvas = canvas;

        if (checkPaint == false) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }

    }

    public void paintRect(Rect rect) {

        int vWidth = getWidth();
        int vHeight = getHeight();

        int l = (int) ((rect.x * vWidth) / mSize.width);
        int t = (int) ((rect.y * vHeight) / mSize.height);
        int r = (int) (((rect.width + rect.x) * vWidth) / mSize.width);
        int b = (int) (((rect.height + rect.y) * vHeight) / mSize.height);


        mCanvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(l, t, r, b), 20, 20, drawingPaint);

    }
```

So, when i call .invalidate() app calls to onDraw, and then when i call .paintRect() paint Rectangle.

I am testing in a nexus 5 so i don't think that problem was device.

Comment: canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); doesn't do anything

Comment: i use this sentence in frames wich not detect faces to "clean" screen

Answer (score 0):

You can't just save a canvas and draw on it later like that.  All of your drawing should be done in onDraw, and if you need to draw a rectangle like that you should save the location to draw it at and draw it the next time onDraw is called.

Comment: but my idea is doing an API to paint rectangles, circles, etc... so i can´t paint in onDraw() because i want create differents functions to differents geometric elements

Comment: Yes you can.  You save the type of object and location in a data structure in the view.  Then in onDraw you draw them.  Storing the canvas for later use isn't valid, you are not promised that it won't change.  The canvas is only valid for the duration of the call.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use preview? do you work with full size?
If you work with full size you need to create preview in background. If it is possible to create preview in background create it for first time and then create preview only for new image.